Calculate Transaction Receipt Root
I made a transaction on a local ethereum network that I spin up on my machine.
After that I fetch the transaction receipt & the block it was processed in, through an ethereum http provider from my local node.
What I am trying to do is calculate the receipt root from the TransactionReceipt that I fetched. To check that the calculation was successful - I equalize it to the receipts_root from the block.
The process of calculation should be as following (according to ethereum's docs):

RLP encode the receipt
Hash the RLP bytes using keccak256 algorithm.

Since this is the only transaction in the block, the hash should match the receipts_root from the fetched block, but sadly that is not the case for me.
My final target is to generate a proof for a single transaction within the receipts merkle tree, and verify this proof against the receipts_root. If there is any other way to do this you're more than welcome to help with this.
This is my example code:
use ethers::prelude::*;
use ethers::providers::Http;
use web3::signing::keccak256;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let provider = Provider::<Http>::try_from("http://localhost:8545")?;
    let hash: H256 = "0xeac9478fa46aa70bba4f6fb4fba391bb69d9218d0e7745778b40d7005b36687c".parse()?;

    let receipt: TransactionReceipt = provider.get_transaction_receipt(hash).await?.unwrap();
    let block_number = receipt.block_number.unwrap().as_u64();
    let block = provider.get_block(block_number).await?.unwrap();

    let receipt_root = block.receipts_root;

    let receipt_rlp = receipt.rlp_bytes();
    let receipt_hash = H256::from(keccak256(receipt_rlp.as_ref()));

    info!("receipt_hash: {:?}", receipt_hash);
    info!("receipt_root: {:?}", receipt_root);
}

Output:
2024-07-18T08:50:47.715711Z  INFO receipt_hash: 0x4219bba977fb65c43cd57a2a2914d778c6051ace56b54769debb52235ad29ac3
2024-07-18T08:50:47.715772Z  INFO receipt_root: 0x036c5edb47bff988d30755bf1b4d735e6f391c8c2b2743752794d6384a5c7796


I also tried 3rd party libraries like these, but without any success (computed hash is not equal to receipts_root as well):
https://github.com/lambdaclass/merkle_patricia_tree
https://github.com/citahub/cita_trie

Solved.
Problem was that I keccak256ed the bytes before inserting into the tree.
Seem like there is no need to do this, and you only need to insert the RLP bytes into the tree.
